# VueJS trigger Checkbox by clicking table row

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm really new to vuejs and I was wondering if it is possible to trigger the checkbox by clicking the table row.

here's a fiddle for you to play.
https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/265410/

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="cat in categories" @click="selectCat(cat)">
        <td><input type="checkbox" :value="cat" v-model="selected" name="" id=""></td>
        <td>{{ cat.code}}</td>
        <td>{{ cat.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button @click="checkData()">Check</button>
</div>
```

**VUEJS**

```
  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
     categories: [
                {code:'HW', name:'Hardware'},
          {code:'SW', name:'Software'},
          {code:'OS', name:'Office Supplies'}
     ],
     selected:[]
    }
  },
  methods:{ 
  selectCat(cat){
    this.selected.push(cat);
  },
 checkData(){
      alert(1);
       console.log(this.selected);
      }
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't that work?

Comment: @Nit I've tried binding an array on it... and create an event on the table row.. get that Item and push on the array.. will update the code give me a second

Comment: @Nit I've already updated the code kindy check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a selected model to your categories and switch that attribute on row click like so:

```
<div id="app">
    <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(cat, index) in categories" :key="index" @click="cat.selected = !cat.selected">
            <td><input type="checkbox" v-model="cat.selected"></td>
            <td>{{ cat.code}}</td>
            <td>{{ cat.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
     categories: [
                {code:'HW', name:'Hardware', selected: false},
          {code:'SW', name:'Software', selected: false},
          {code:'OS', name:'Office Supplies', selected: false}
     ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
  }
})
```

Manipulating the state of natives components should always be done by changing their v-model, rather than going into the DOM and and setting a selected attribute. Basically let your model define the state of your view.

Here's another version that'll use a separate array for handling the selected state:

```
<div id="app">
    <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(cat, index) in categories" :key="index" @click="toggleSelect(cat)">
            <td><input type="checkbox" :checked="selected.includes(cat.code)"></td>
            <td>{{ cat.code}}</td>
            <td>{{ cat.name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
     categories: [
          {code:'HW', name:'Hardware'},
          {code:'SW', name:'Software'},
          {code:'OS', name:'Office Supplies'}
     ],
     selected: ['HW']
    }
  },
  methods:{
    toggleSelect (cat) {

      if (this.selected.includes(cat.code)) {
        this.selected.splice(this.selected.findIndex(v => v === cat.code), 1)
      } else {
        this.selected.push(cat.code)
      }
    } 
  }
})
```

Comment: is there way for accessing the child element of the tr? what I want is just to actually toggle the checkbox by clicking the table row.. since I get the selected category into an array.

Comment: Yes that's totally possible BUT not the vue way. Vue abstracts the dom manipulation away from you, so that you can focus on manipulating your data. I think there's a better way to still make it work with having the selected attribute in a separate array without having to manipulate the dom itself, let me quickly update my answer.

Comment: @SamTengWong I've updated my post to contain a newer version that'll outsource the selected categories to its own array. Hope that fits your needs better. Note that it has one value pre-selected, if you don't want that, just delete it from the selected array in the data. Note that we never manipulate the DOM, just the data and let vue do the manipulation for us. That's the core concept you have to remember whenever using vue.